# PHP - Use preg_replace to change a colour of word after a specific character

Tags: php, sql

I currently have preg-replace in place to change the colours of words that display in a div.

however at the moment it is simply just text matches.

```
if (sqlsrv_has_rows($stmt)) 
        {
            $data = sqlsrv_fetch_array( $stmt, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);

            echo "<div class='custom-font title-container'>
                    <div class='expand-button-container fa fa-expand' onclick='expandWindow()'></div>
                    <div id='title-container1'><div class='edit-note fa fa-pencil' onclick='editSQLNote()'>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</div>" . "<div data-toggle='modal' data-target='#editSQLNoteNameModal' class='display-inline'>" . $data['SQLNoteName'] . "</div>" . "&nbsp;<div class='save-note fa fa-thumbs-up' onclick='saveSQLNote(); submitSQLNoteText();'></div></div>
                  </div>";

            $note = nl2br($data['SQLNote']);
            $note = preg_replace('%(SELECT|FROM|WHERE|INNER|JOIN|DISTINCT|LEFT|OUTER|APPLY|WITH|NOLOCK|DECLARE|ORDER BY|VARCHAR|bit)%m', '<span style="color: red;">$1</span>', $note);
            $note = preg_replace('%(ISNULL|UPDATE|SET|INSERT INTO)%m', '<span style="color: #9A2EFE;">$1</span>', $note);          
            $note = preg_replace('%(IS NOT NULL|AND|IS NULL)%m', '<span style="color: grey;">$1</span>', $note);
            $note = preg_replace('%(BEGIN TRAN|ROLLBACK TRAN|BEGIN|END|CASE|END|WHEN|THEN|ELSE)%m', '<span style="color: blue;">$1</span>', $note);
            $note = preg_replace('%(GETDATE|MAX|CONVERT|UPDATE|CAST|COUNT)%m', '<span style="color: #FA58F4;">$1</span>', $note);

            echo "<div contenteditable='true' id='ta4'>" . $note . "</div>";
        } 
        else 
        {
            echo "No data found";
        }
```

However i would like to know if there is a way so if i put an @ symbol what ever the next word is up until the space after the word the colour changes.

So if i put @hello and @goodbye they will change to green (including the @ symbol but only up until the end of the word)

however i can't hard code the words to be hello and goodbye because they will always be different (These will be declared variables by a user so always different).

So is there a way to dynamically change the colour of the words after an @ symbol?

I apologise if this doesnt make sense, i tried to explain the best i could.

Comment: Use correct regexp, isn't it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this will do it:

```
$note = preg_replace('%(@.+?\b)%m', '<span style="color: green;">$1</span>', $note);
```

`.+?` is a non-greedy match until the first `\b` which is a word boundary (space, but also characters such as `,`, `.` and newline).

Comment: Fantastic, did the job perfectly! Will mark as answer as soon as it allows me (6 mins from now xD)